# My keyboard stops taking inputs suddenly. How can I debug the issue?

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-mate, xserver

I can't find a pattern in it, when it happens. Everything's working fine and suddenly keyboard stops responding. Mouse works well. Possible fixs I have tried:

1. Restart solves the issue( I used it for few days).
2. Recently I tried hitting ctrl+alt+f2 and switched back to GUI again by ctrl+alt+f7. And everything works fine again.
   I doubt system is taking keyboard inputs well but the text fields(browser location bar, terminal) doesn't respond. Because ctrl_alt_f2 works fine as I've said. I can't reproduce the error on my will. It happens automatically. So it's getting very difficult to debug.

Any idea what might be the cause? Any suggestion how I can debug this next time, when it appears?
My system specification: Ubuntu Mate 20.04(completely up to date)

Comment: Have you checked error logs afterwards? `sudo dmesg | less` Is your keyboard a wired keyboard? Wireless? Bluetooth?

Comment: It's the kyboard on my laptop. I never tried external keyboard during this issue. I will  check and post the `dmesg` op next time.

Comment: I ran into the error again. and after that I generated `dmesg` log. now what to look for?

Comment: Did you see anything amiss in the logs? If not, post a copy of them by editing your question.